# Rename bands in a multiband raster in ArcGIS 10.x

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, multi-band

I have imported a multiband raster in .tif format into a geodatabase using ArcGIS 10.7 and want to rename the bands to something more descriptive. However, I can't find out how to do this easily.

Does anyone know how to rename bands in ArcGIS 10.7?

Comment: According to https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-classes/raster-object.htm there is no arcpy.Raster().bandNames attribute - are you sure you can get the band names this way?  It errors when I try it.  Please [edit] your question to include the error message you receive.

Comment: You are correct. I forgot I was using ArcGIS Pro in a script when I added that. I removed the arcpy scripting section. Still not sure how to rename bands.